# Is there any kind of metaprogramming in C?

Tags: c

I know that there are some possibilities os metaprogramming in languages like Python and Java. We can introspect the functions, classes, types of an object and modify them at runtime.

Is it possible to do something similar in C?

Comment: No. None of that information is stored at runtime unless you explicitly store it.

Comment: No, but see [Object-Oriented Programming With ANSI-C](https://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf) - old, but shows how it can be done. Gtk makes use of a similar approach. (but is also where Gtk became increasingly unwieldy to work with...)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin But it is not clear for me how can we do metaprogramming with these techniques. That is...Using these techniques it is possible to introspect the functions, classes, types of an object and modify them at runtime?

Comment: It would be tedious, but you could compile with `-g` to get debug info into the object files(s). Then, you could use (e.g.) `libelf` to inspect things at runtime.

Comment: While C doesn't have the requisite facilities like reflection or code generation, that hasn't stopped some people from implementing some truly *evil* hacks in older projects that, in hindsight, we've all realized were a really bad idea. Like [m4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_(computer_language)).

Comment: @Zaratruta it isn't a perfect example and will not provide the level you will find in Python or C++, but the approach gives the ability to define whatever class functions (pointers within a struct), you want to get information back or modify behavior at runtime. (essentially getters and setters, etc..) That's largely why the first word in the original comment was "No", but depending on what functionality you need, you can write it. But I agree with CraigEsley -- it will be tedious -- always is when you are reinventing a very large wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: "No".

- Java and C# (among others) support [reflection](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html): the ability to examine and manipulate a class from within itself at runtime
- JavaScript, PHP, Lua and Perl (among others) are considered "[Dynamic programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language)": they can be modified on-the-fly as the program executes.

"Static languages" like C, C++, FORTRAN, etc. have no such capabilities.

You can, to some extent, "emulate" similar functionality.  But it's not directly supported by the language itself, and any such "emulations" will almost inevitably have "limitations".

Comment: Note that metaprogramming does not have to mean run-time reflection; it can also happen at compile time.
Which is not available in C either, beyond the most fundamental kind available to all languages, namely manually parsing in source files and generating new ones as a pre-build step.

Comment: C++ aficionados sometimes refer to templates ("generics") as "metaprogramming".  Some might also consider C macros as "metaprogramming". I don't want to quarrel with them.  But the OP clearly implied the ability to examine, alter and/or inject code dynamically, at runtime.